# Sorting rows automatic by priority

Tags: html, datatable

What is the best way to make a table sort rows automatic? Like, I have a priority columns based on data coming from database, when the settled date comes, the row go to the top automatically. I don't have the code yet, I'm searching the best way to do it, so I'm asking some tips here. If you know how to do it using datatables will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you provided no code, or a clear use case. It's a bit hard to pin point the exact answer for your question. Yet, I believe you can model your solution better if take a look at [sort](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) which is a built in functionality of datatable.

Comment: I'm sorry if i was not so clear. Being more precisely, i want sort rows of a table based on datetime column coming from database but automatically. the user set a limit date, when this date comes the row goes to the top of table like a priority task, and in realtime, without refresh page.

Comment: Assuming the newer the data, the higher the priority you can use sort and set it to the column containing the dates and set the second parameter to 'asc' so that it'd display the newest at the top. I hope this helps, bud.

Comment: do you know where i can find it more detailed, a documentation or something to study?

Comment: Their documentation, dude.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/order